# Swift 4 端末のスリープ回数

Tags: swift, swift4

今現在、Swift4を使用しているのですが、端末のスリープ回数を得たいと考えております。アプリのスリープ時や、起動時はAppDelegate.swiftでコードを書くということはわかりました。アプリではなく、端末のスリープ回数を得るにはどのようなコードを使用すればよいのでしょうか。よければ教えていただきたいです。

Answer (score 2):

通常は不可能です。iOSアプリが動作していられるのは基本的にはアプリケーションがフォアグラウンドにあるときだけで、バックグラウンドの動作は非常に限定的な時間しか動作できません。

一部の目的のアプリにだけ例外的に長時間バックグラウンドの動作が可能ですが、その場合でもデバイスのスリープのタイミングを取得するといったAPIは基本的にありません。

よって、そのようなアプリを作ることは通常は不可能になります。